# Radnom flutter error in IntelliJ IDE when launching IDE

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I have the flutter plugin installed and I have given it the location of my flutter SDK as well as dart (plugin and SDK) whenever I start up the IDE I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4586)
    at io.flutter.editor.FlutterColorProvider.getColorFrom(FlutterColorProvider.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ui.ColorLineMarkerProvider.lambda$collectSlowLineMarkers$0(ColorLineMarkerProvider.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionProcessingHelper.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionProcessingHelper.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionPointName.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.ui.ColorLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(ColorLineMarkerProvider.java:46)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:225)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectMarkers$2(LineMarkersPass.java:107)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:95)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectMarkers(LineMarkersPass.java:103)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:76)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:57)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$1(PassExecutorService.java:390)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceKt.runWithSpanIgnoreThrows(trace.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceUtil.runWithSpanThrows(TraceUtil.java:24)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:386)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1133)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$3(PassExecutorService.java:377)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:376)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:352)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:207)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:350)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
```

Not sure what this means or what to do

I have gone into the settings of the plugins and made sure everything is set up correctly but so far as I can see I can't find any problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's an exception from the Flutter plugin. It appears to be [reported a lot](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues). If it doesn't affect your work, you can just ignore it. Otherwise you will have to uninstall the plugin or hope that a fix will be released soon.

Comment: If IntelliJ IDEA keeps giving the same error, you could try Android Studio for your Flutter development.